# Conditional format cell if surrounding values are not in ascending/descending order

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a large book with one column of values:

| A |
| --- |
| **Type** |
| 90 |
| 91 |
| 92 |
| 92 |
| 94 |
| 93 |
| 95 |
| 96 |
| 95 |

Where I want to colour the ones that are not in ascending/descending successive order.

In this case I want to colour the 94, 93 and the 96 after.

The formula I tried:

`=OR(AND($A2 < $A1; $A2 < $A3);AND($A2 > $A1; $A2 > $A3))`

But this doesn't work. I don't really see what I'm doing wrong, and maybe there is another simpler way of solving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but I believe there's something wrong in your formula: instead of:

```
=OR(AND($A2 < $A1; $A2 < $A3);AND($A2 > $A1; $A2 > $A3))
```

Try this:

```
=OR(AND($A1 < $A2; $A2 < $A3);AND($A1 > $A2; $A2 > $A3))
          ^     ^                   ^     ^
          ^     ^                   ^     ^
```

(The `^` clarify where you went wrong)

Comment: it improves a bit, it still doesn't work though

Comment: @B.Quaink: what is the problem you're having now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula within your format condition:

`=OR((A2-1)=A1,(A2=A1),(N(A1)=0))=FALSE`